# I can't use any library that uses linking in an ejected bare expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

I ejected my project a few days ago to use so components in Android that weren't available for expo projects like a background module that can handle notifications but I can't use a single one. I tried the react-native-background-job, react-native-background-fetch, react-native-background-task but all gave a similar error message:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNBackgroundFetch.configure')]

Where 'evaluating X' had different X for each module. I tried checking if I missed any installation steps but I couldn't find anything wrong and since it's for many modules I guess it's a from a common cause which I can't solve individually. Thanks in advance for the attention

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Expo can't run the libraries that require linking even when ejected. For that you have to use

```
react-native start
```

in it's own terminal window to start the metro and

```
npx react-native run-android
```

In a separate window